# Postfix: How to make complex attachment filtering?

Tags: postfix, spam-filter

I have Postfix on our server. 
I need to filter attachments in incoming mail not only by it type, but also check what inside of it. Exactly by now I need to filter attachment that:

- is a .zip archive
- contains .exe inside archive
- is about 10-20k of size

Is it possible to pass attachment to external script? (Actually I'm able to write script that analyze the above conditions) Is it possible using Postfix only or do I need some external tool like spammassasin or Amavis?

Comment: use clamav https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostfixVirtualMailBoxClamSmtpHowto

Comment: Can it filter attachments using those complex rules?  I mean that every day I receive e-mails with 0day viruses that not detected by most antiviruses by the moment of receiving: neither ClamAV, KAV, DrWeb, Symantec, AVG, etc. Even with highest heuristics settings or things like KSN. I checked it on Virustotal. If you suggest to install ClamAV as antivirus I am afraid it will be useless. (Anyway thanks for idea. I will check it)

Comment: You need content filtering like Amavisd. This [article](http://www.akadia.com/services/postfix_amavisd.html) gives some useful hints on the possible configuration. It's rather old and you should not use it as an installation guide, but it explains roles of different programs and how they may be fit together.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to pass attachment to external script? (Actually I'm able to write script that analyze the above conditions)

If you have some capabilities to creating a script to checks such conditions, then you may interested in this page: [Postfix simple content filter](http://www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html#simple_filter). With this feature, your script will read email content via stdin. You can also pass some variable like sender, recipient, etc.

Of course the script needs to extract the attachment as postfix doesn't have capabilities to extract it. Another downside is you can't filter email submitted by `mail` command, such as email generated by PHP script in your server.

If this feature doesn't meet your needs, then you may look into [advanced content filter section](http://www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html#advanced_filter).